Mean value theorem application for a theorem on concave functions
Let $f$ be a function with continuous third derivative, with $f'$ strictly convex
on $(−\infty, 0)$ and strictly concave on $(0,\infty)$. Prove that there exist only two differentiable functions $a \colon (0,\infty) \rightarrow (−\infty, 0)$ and $b \colon (−\infty, 0) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that for any $l > 0$ holds the following:
$$\frac{f'(a) + f'(b)}{2} = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}, a = a(l), b = b(l), b - a = l.$$
My teacher gave us this theorem without proof, but I am curious how it can be done. I thought this could be solved with Lagrange's mean value theorem, but I don't know how to apply it here. Do you have any ideas?
